# Integrate Crystal Report to Progress Webspeed web application

Tags: web-applications, crystal-reports, report, progress, webspeed

Is there any way to integrate Crystal Report to Webspeed web application ? If not, is there any official source state that it can't be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSpeed pretty much can do everything a "normal" Progress 4GL program can do so the limits here really should be more about deploying Crystal Report in a web environment.

Checking the official Progress Knowledgebase [here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/) gives nothing, neither does the Progress Development Network [here](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/index.jspa) so the answer to your second question is "no".